# Равномерное выравнивание элементов по ширине

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Мне необходимо сделать 5 кнопок в ряд внизу экрана, как это реализовано в соцсети "Вконтакте", чтобы 5 кнопок одинакового размера были равноудалены друг от друга и при этом крайние кнопки были привязаны к краям экрана. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Хорошим решением оказалось использовать LinearLayout и задать значение атрибута android:weightSum="5" (или другое число, кол-во элементов в ряду) и android:layout_weight="1" для каждого элемента, чтобы ряд кнопок находился снизу:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 3"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 4"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 5"/>
```